# sed matching lines beginning with * and //

Tags: linux, unicode, sed, string-matching

I wanna convert some java files and replace the umlauts Ö,ä and ü as unicode.

Here's my sed line:

```
sed -i '{ /^(#|\*$)/!s/0xE4/0xE4/g;/#/!s/Ä/0xC4/g;/#/!s/ö/0xF6/g;/#/!s/Ö/0xD6/g;/#/!s/ü/0xFC/g;/#/!s/Ü/0xDC/g; }'
```

scenario:

Before sed it looks like :

```
# comment with umlauts ÄÄÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖÖ

ÖÖÖÖÖÖÖÖÖ

// comment with umlauts ÄÄÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖÖ

 Text text text ÄÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖÖ

/*
 * comment with umlauts ÄÄÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖÖ
 */
```

After it should looks like that :

```
 # comment with umlauts ÄÄÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖÖ

 0xD60xD60xD60xD60xD60xD60xD60xD60xD60xD60xD60xD6

// comment with umlauts ÄÄÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖÖ

 Text text text 0xC40xC40xC40xC40xC40xD60xD60xD60xD60xD6


/*
 * comment with umlauts ÄÄÄÄÄÄÖÖÖÖÖ
 */
```

Could anyone help me with the matching? - I"ve got but it doesn't works right:

```
/^(#|\*$)/!
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Substituting characters with umlauts that appear outside of comments for what? Java unicode escapes (\u1234)? The string "0x12"? The character 0x12?

Answer (score 2):

#### Posix sed

```
sed '\%^ *\(#\|//\|\*\|/\*\)%!{
 s/Ä/0xC4/g
 s/ö/0xF6/g
 s/Ö/0xD6/g
 s/ü/0xFC/g
 s/Ü/0xDC/g
}'
```

#### GNU sed

```
sed -r '\%^ *(#|//|\*|/\*)%!{
 s/Ä/0xC4/g
 s/ö/0xF6/g
 s/Ö/0xD6/g
 s/ü/0xFC/g
 s/Ü/0xDC/g
}'
```

*Updated with ninjalj's comments. An actual ninja edit!*

Comment: That would look much cleaner using `\%regex%` instead of `/regex/`, and since there is a `linux` tag, using `sed -r`.

Comment: @ninjalj +1 for the comment incase the OP wants to go that route, but I prefer portability.

Comment: @ninjalj: actually, I do agree with you on the `%` regex delimiter. Updated

Answer (score 0):

`sed` uses basic regular expressions, so you have to write `(` as `\(` and `|` as `\|`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've changed the my sed matching  `sed -i '{ /^\(#\|\*$\|\\\\\)/!` but he still replaces the umlauts in the lines which starting with * and // .

Comment: I group some sed statements together `sed -i '{ /^\(#\|\*\|\\\\\)/!s/0xE4/0xE4/g;/#/!s/Ä/0xC4/g;/#/!s/ö/0xF6/g;/#/!s/Ö/0xD6/g;/#/!s/ü/0xFC/g;/#/!s/Ü/0xDC/g; }' {} \ `

Comment: Now it's only matching `*` at the start of the line, but in your example, you want it to match at the start of the line, or near the start of the line after some spaces.